# open_basedir restriction error in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, open-basedir

I can't figure out how to fix this:

```
Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(./codeigniter/logs/log-2010-11-12.php) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs:/tmp) in 
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/codeigniter/libraries/Log.php on line 92
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open_basedir means php is restricted to the folders it can include files from. Basically the file you are trying to get cannot be accessed, you'll need to move it or change your php settings

Comment: But isn't that file inside of the httpdocs folder, and so shouldn't it be allowed?